# Architecture and abstraction levels mixing issue

Tags: java, c#, oop, architecture, abstraction

I'm calling out for experienced developers on an architecture question.

Imagine I have a class HighBusinessLogic:

```
public class HighBusinessLogic{
  public void DoBusiness1(){
  }
  public void DoBusiness2(){
  }
  public void DoBusiness3(){
  }
}
```

Now this class uses a lower business logic class to do stuff (like a db repository).

```
public class HighBusinessLogic{
  private LowBusinessLogic _lowBusinessLogic;

  public HighBusinessLogic(LowBusinessLogic lowBusinessLogic){
    _lowBusinessLogic = lowBusinessLogic;
  }

  public void DoBusiness1(){
    // some code
    _lowBusinessLogic.DoThing(someData)
    // some other code
  }
  public void DoBusiness2(){
    // some code
    _lowBusinessLogic.DoThing(someData)
    // some other code
  }
  public void DoBusiness3(){
    // some code
    _lowBusinessLogic.DoAnotherThing(someData)
    // some other code
  }
}
```

Alright, finally, it happens that their is a lot of time where when I call lowBusinessLogic.DoThing I have to repeat the exact same treatment with the data before.

```
public class HighBusinessLogic{
  private LowBusinessLogic _lowBusinessLogic;

  public HighBusinessLogic(LowBusinessLogic lowBusinessLogic){
    _lowBusinessLogic = lowBusinessLogic;
  }

  public void DoBusiness1(){
    // some code
    DoStuffWithData(someData)        <-- here
    _lowBusinessLogic.DoThing(someData)
    // some other code
  }
  public void DoBusiness2(){
    // some code
    DoStuffWithData(someData)      <-- here
    _lowBusinessLogic.DoThing(someData)
    // some other code
  }
  public void DoBusiness3(){
    // some code
    _lowBusinessLogic.DoAnotherThing(someData)
    // some other code
  }
}
```

I will be tempted to create an intermediate level of abstraction with a new class doing both of DoStuffWithData and DoThing.

```
public class IntermediateBusinessLogic{
  private LowBusinessLogic _lowBusinessLogic;

  public IntermediateBusinessLogic(LowBusinessLogic lowBusinessLogic){
    _lowBusinessLogic = lowBusinessLogic;
  }

  public DoStuffWithDataAndDoThings(Data someData){
    DoStuffWithData(someData)
    _lowBusinessLogic.DoThing(someData)
  }
}

public class HighBusinessLogic{
  private LowBusinessLogic _lowBusinessLogic;
  private IntermediateBusinessLogic _intermediateBusinessLogic;

  public HighBusinessLogic(
    LowBusinessLogic lowBusinessLogic,
    IntermediateBusinessLogic intermediateBusinessLogic)
  {
    _lowBusinessLogic = lowBusinessLogic;
    _intermediateBusinessLogic = intermediateBusinessLogic;
  }

  public void DoBusiness1(){
    // some code
    _intermediateBusinessLogic.DoStuffWithDataAndDoThings(someData)
    // some other code
  }
  public void DoBusiness2(){
    // some code
    _intermediateBusinessLogic.DoStuffWithDataAndDoThings(someData)
    // some other code
  }
  public void DoBusiness3(){
    // some code
    _lowBusinessLogic.DoAnotherThing(someData)
    // some other code
  }
}
```

But then, I'm mixing to levels of abstraction because DoBusiness3 still uses a low level method without the intermediate treatment.

My question is : is that ok??

Some says you should create a function DoAnotherThing inside the intermediate class that just forward the call to the low business layer. But by doing so, you can really quickly have an interface (intermediate one) with a tone and a tone of methods, most of them being only forward calls to the lower level and even worse has a lot of actions not related to each others inside it (and therefore break SOLID principle).

Is their a real issue of referencing the intermediate level and lower level from the same class? And if so, what are the possible issues other than "it's dirty"?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Think objects not classes. Analyze what each object does. Is any of your objects have multiple purposes? If yes, separate these objects in smaller ones. A good indicator is to have a constructor with maximum 3 parameters. In situation you are using MVC or Service Dao strategies just applying these design patterns will solve a lot of troubles. Layered architecture can help, the rule is one layer can work only with nearest layer. In case of MVC-Service-Dao, the best way is the controller to call service, service will call Dao, and **not** vice-versa. If you need you can have controller to call a business layer, that will call low lever logic service layer, splitting service in two layers.
https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/software-architecture-patterns/9781491971437/ch01.html#idm46407728109088

Comment: My question is more about a generic case without talking about layers. But in my specific case if you want to answer for this scenario: I will have A on the Business level, calling B also on the business level and C on the infra level. But B also calls C. Should I make it so A only calls B and therefore I have to write one method on B to forward any calls to C from A. Or is it ok to have A calling B and C even if B already calls C.